# Execute specific function based on user input in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, function, hashlib

I am making a python script which hashes a string using an algorithm that the user specifies in input using hashlib. After I hash the string, I want to do the same thing to it, no matter what hash algorithm the user chose. Because of that I wanted to make a function for it, not to repeat code but wouldn't know how to change the built-in hash function based on the input. My code right now looks like this:

```
current_algorithm = input('Hash algorithm: ')    

if current_algorithm == 'md5':
    hashed = hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest()
    # Execute the same code here
elif current_algorithm == 'sha256':
    hashed = hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest()
    # Execute the same code here 
elif current_algorithm == 'sha512':
    hashed = hashlib.sha512(word).hexdigest()
    # Execute the same code here
```

The function `hashlib.algorithm(word).hexdigest()` has to change depending on which algorithm the user chose. For example, if the user chose sha512, the code would look like this: `hashlib.sha512(word).hexdigest()`, instead, if the user chose md5, the code would look like this: `hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest()` and so on. However, the code under these lines is exactly the same and right now I am repeating it 3 times, and possibly more if I will add more algorithms in the future. Therefore how do I make a function that changes algorithm based on user input, so that I do not have to repeat so much code? I was thinking to take advantage of arguments, but wouldn't know how to work around it. This is kind of what I had in mind, but would not work since you can't change built-in methods:

```
def func(algorithm):
    hashlib.algorithm(word).hexdigest()
    # Execute the same code here

if current_algorithm == 'md5':
    func(current_algorithm)
elif current_algorithm == 'sha256':
    func(current_algorithm)
elif current_algorithm == 'sha512':
    func(current_algorithm)
```

Then, under every if statement I would call the function with and passing it the user input (containing the hash algorithm) as an argument.

I hope the question is clear and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string) (I'm guessing this would be useful for you since you want to call a function name which has the algo in it's name, there for you should be able to stitch something together like `hashlib.'+userinput)

Comment: You can pass a function as a value in a dictionary or Pandas data frame, maybe this could help you, test = {"key": func}

Comment: @Torxed You are right, that post would have helped me a lot. I am sorry I did not see it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
import hashlib

current_algorithm = input('Hash algorithm: ')    
try:
    hashed = getattr(hashlib, current_algorithm)(word).hexdigest()
except AttributeError:
    print('Invalid algorithm choice')
```

Comment: This one works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply extract the common code from the `if/else` block like this:

```
current_algorithm = input('Hash algorithm: ')    

if current_algorithm == 'md5':
    hashed = hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest()
elif current_algorithm == 'sha256':
    hashed = hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest()
elif current_algorithm == 'sha512':
    hashed = hashlib.sha512(word).hexdigest()

# Execute the same code here (using hashed variable)
```